# What are the depicted measurement devices called in English?

Tags: word-request, expressions, image-identification

Please check the image. What is it called in English?[image: Metal tape measure]

Is it as 'a measurement indicator'?

How about this one?

[image: Fabric tape measure]

Comment: It is a measuring tape.

Comment: They're both *tape measures* (or, as @shin says, *measuring tapes*); one's a carpenter's tape measure, the other's a tailor's tape measure.

Comment: By the way, if you are trying to find out what something in a picture is called in English, you can use Google.  Go to http://images.google.com/ and drag the image into the search box, and Google will give you its best guess what it is.

Answer (score 6):

**Measuring tape,** or *tape measures*.

The first image is for carpentry and other construction and surveying, the second one is for tailors or others to measure in order to fit clothes for you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_measure

Answer (score 2):

In practice, the terms "tape measure" and "measuring tape" are not interchangeable (in American English).

The first image shows a "tape measure".  As Nihilist_Frost points out, construction workers use tape measures to measure more-or-less straight distances.

The second image shows a "measuring tape".  As Nihilist_Frost points out, seamstresses use measuring tapes to measure curved or flexible things, like distances along people or cloth.

Where possible, American surveyors tend to use laser levels and laser distance measuring equipment instead of tape measures.  Laser measurements are less sensitive to temperature, and levels can prevent errors due to slopes.